# UITableView header view overlap cells in iOS 10

Tags: ios, uitableview

There's a simple `UITableView` in my app, and there's a custom view for the `tableView.tableHeaderView` property. When this property is set, the view has the correct size (full width, about 45px high).

```
[_resultHeaderView sizeToFit]; // the view as the correct frame
[_resultTableView setTableHeaderView:_resultHeaderView];
```

In iOS 9 and previous versions, the header displays correctly, but in iOS 10, the cells start at the same Y coordinate as my header view, so my header view appears over the first cell.

Setting these properties also have no effect:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Has something changed in iOS 10 that could explain this different behavior? What would be a good solution?

Thanks

Comment: It's not a header of a section, but rather the whole tableview header. (The sections don't have headers). I am refering to this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview?language=objc. Plus, my setup works in iOS 9 and below, so I don't think that's the issue...

Comment: Why did this question got -1 ? It would be nice to explain so I can improve my participation here...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The bug was in the fact that the view was being resized automatically, so its frame height really was 0 when it was being attached to the tableView, which explains the behavior.

Setting the autoresizingMask to none fixed this bug.

`_headerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone`

Again, it wasn't necessary in iOS 9 and below. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: to set a UIViewAutoresizing value to UIViewAutoresizingNone in Swift 3, set it to []

Comment: For Swift 4, something like `_headerView.autoresizingMask = []`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more Swift approach

```swift
tableView.tableHeaderView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Or you can do it directly in your header

```swift
 myHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Also you must call these two delegate methods.

```swift
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return yourHeaderView
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30 // Your preferred height
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set `headerView.frame` before `tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView`